# Printing first and last name from first name, last name to last name, first name

Tags: java, printing

The formatName method should
accept a String called name that contains a name in the format "First Last". You may assume that
there is only one space in the String. The method should create and return a String that contains the name
in the format "Last, First".

```
public static void formatName ( String name ) {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in);

 String firstName;
 String lastName;
 int index;


 System.out.println(" Enter First Name : ");
 firstName = scan.nextLine();

 System.out.println(" Enter Last Name : ");
 lastName = scan.nextLine();

 for ( int i = 0; i < lastName (); i++){
    for ( int x = 0; x < firstName(); x++){

 name += firstName.charAt(i);
 name += lastName.charAt(x);

 return name;
    }
 }

}//end formatName
```

Comment: This just looks like a copy of a homework question or exercise. What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: my bad should had inputted the code

Comment: But im trying to switch first name and last name to last name, first name ex/ john doe, doe john

Comment: Looks like your code is all commented out. You are trying to access the names a character at a time. You don't need to do that. Just work with them at the string level. You don't need to pass `name` as an argument. What would you pass? You're using it as a local variable to hold your final result that you ultimate just return.

Comment: First, *should create and return a String* so the method should not be `void`. Second, you should be operating on the `name` argument, not prompting for more input. Third, you should be looking for a space in that argument. Fourth, once you know where the space is you should be able to format the parts of the `String` on the left and right of that space as a new `String`.

Comment: You may find the [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) and [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) methods of `String` helpful.  But if you have to, you can accomplish this with nothing more than [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) and the `+` operator.

Comment: Also `Strings` are immutable.

Comment: Hi, please add more about what you tried already and why that didn't work for the use case. Like sample input and output and why the output is not as expected.

Comment: Or, use a *regular expression*, one line method: `return name.replaceAll("\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s*", "$2, $1");`

Answer (score 0):

Your formatName method is more complex than it should. The requirement is to take one single String with firstname (space) lastname and return lastname (comma space) firstname.

The User input should take place outside of the formatName method.

Check the example below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in);
        System.out.println(" Enter Name : ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input: " + name);
        System.out.println("Formated: " + formatName(name));
    }

    public static String formatName ( String name ) throws Exception {
        String[] nameTokenized = name.split(" ");
        if (nameTokenized.length!=2){
            throw new Exception("Incorrect Name");
        }
        String firstName = nameTokenized[0];
        String lastName = nameTokenized[1];

        return lastName + ", " + firstName;
    }//end formatName
```

In the main method, the User can input a single String (name). The code calls the `formatName(name)` method for that input String and expects the method to return a String which is printed on console.

The formatName method splits the name String into parts that are stored inside an array (nameTokenized). If the length of the array is not 2, meaning that there are not exactly to names with a space between them, an exception is thrown.

If the input (name) is correct, the firstName and lastName variables are set and the method returns the String in the format lastname(comma space)firstname.

Sample output:

```
 Enter Name : 
Joe Doe
Input: Joe Doe
Formated: Doe Joe
```

With incorrect input

```
 Enter Name : 
Joe Doe Doe
Input: Joe Doe Doe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Incorrect Name
    at Main2.formatName(Main2.java:17)
    at Main2.main(Main2.java:11)
```